# Getting the population growth at a given year

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this equation which is a model of growth for a given population:

$$ x'=(a-bx)x, (a,b>0) $$

And i have this data:

$$t_0 = 1900, x_0= 1984115 $$ $$t_1=1991, x_1=6059311 $$ and $a=0.0470419$ is the growth rhythm

How do i use this data to get the population at $t_2=2003$?

If i integrate the equation i end up having:

$$ x(t)= \frac{at^2}{2}+\frac{bt^3}{3}$$

And if i implement the data of $t_0$ and $x_0$, the solution should be $x_2'= -337.0562$, but i know this is not correct.

Comment: You do not have $x'=(a-bt)t$ , which could be simply integrated, but the differential equation $x'=(a-bx)x$ , the solution of which is much complicater.

Comment: But even if you have $x'=(a-bt)t$, the solution is $x(t)=\frac{at^2}{2}-\frac{bt^3}{3}$

Comment: I think that $x'=(a-bt)t$ is meant and that you simply made a sign-error.

Comment: Ok, so i have $t= \frac{ax^2}{2} - \frac{bx^3}{3}$, now if i implement $t_0$ and $x_0$ i get that b is a really small number and i don't even know why i had $t_1$ and $x_1$ if i didn't need it, so i think i am still wrong.

Comment: You mean $x=\frac{at^2}{2}-\frac{bt^3}{3}$. This should give a reasonable $b$.

Comment: I am also confused why $a$ AND two points are given.

Comment: Please check the exercise again!

Comment: Maybe it has to be seen like: $\frac{dx}{dt}= (0.0470419+bx)x$ so i get $ ln|0.0470419+bx| = xt$?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%27%3D%28a-bx%29x

shows you the function $x(t)$ fulfilling the given differential equation.

Insert the two given points to find out the values for $a$ and $b$.